# Robot Framework if-condition fails

Tags: if-statement, robotframework

Why is this if-clause not true when ${orderrowlist} contains data (it is a list of lists)?

```
${orderrowlist}=  Run Keyword If  '${orderrowlist}'== '${EMPTY}'  Set variable  ${tmp}
```

I log `orderrowlist` just before this if as well as directly after. The first logging list the expected data while at the second logging the content of `orderrowlist` is replaced with the content of `tmp`

Answer (score 1):

> Why does is this if-clause not true when ${orderrowlist} contains data (it is a list of lists)?
>
> `${orderrowlist}=  Run Keyword If  '${orderrowlist}'== '${EMPTY}'  Set variable  ${tmp}`

Why is it false when the `${orderrowlist}` is not empty? Because a non-empty list is not equal to an empty string.

> The first logging list the expected data while at the second logging the content of orderrowlist is replaced with the content of tmp

That is because you are explicitly setting the value of the variable to the result of the keyword.

---

Normally, to set a variable based on a condition you should use [Set variable if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If) rather than [Run keyword if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If). With the former you can provide two values: one if the condition is true and one if it is false. If you want the variable to be unchanged, you can use the existing value as the "false" value.

Here's an example:

```
*** Variables ***
${var}  original value

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${var}=  set variable if  '${var}' == '${EMPTY}'  new value  ${var}
    should be equal as strings  ${var}  original value

    ${var}=  set variable if  '${var}' == 'original value'  new value  ${var}
    should be equal as strings  ${var}  new value
```

Comment: So how do I formulate it? If orderrowlist is empty I want to populate it with tmp, otherwise nothing.

Comment: "Why is it false when the ${orderrowlist} is not empty? Because a non-empty list is not equal to an empty string." - and then the content of `orderrowlist` must not be replaced by `tmp` - but it is!?